# awk for Sorting of duplicate userid based on login time difference (Timestamp)

Tags: awk, duplicates

Below is sample log file

```
aa001 2014/5/28 17:40  
aa001 2014/5/28 18:40  
bb002 2014/5/26 10:00  
bb002 2014/5/28 7:00  
bb002 2014/5/28 10:30  
bb002 2014/5/28 11:31  
bb002 2014/5/28 12:31  
cc003 2014/5/28 11:25  
dd004 2014/5/28 13:47  
dd004 2014/5/28 16:53  
dd004 2014/5/28 19:59  
dd004 2014/5/28 20:02   
dd004 2014/5/28 20:04  
dd004 2014/5/28 22:04  
ww005 2014/5/28 11:09  
zz006 2014/5/28 9:27  
zz006 2014/5/28 10:00
```

Using `awk` I like to print only those user ids which have multiple log in sessions and that too only those user id which have 2nd session open for more than 2 hours.

I like to get following result (userid as well as total logins against this user id)

```
bb002 5  
dd004 6
```

Note.

1. aa001 and  zz006 have multiple logins but the login time difference between two logins is less than 2hrs
2. User logins can be from different date e.g.  bb002 2014/5/26 and 2014/5/28,
3. Login file usually  less than 100 lines.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated on June 01 2014 by user3685993**
Below is what I have tried, I am getting the results I want, but the codeing is not very concise, like what Jaypal’s  coding.

```
#!/bin/ksh93      
#!/bin/bash      
while read user dt tm    
do      
   u_epoch_time=$( printf "%(%s)T" "${dt} ${tm}" )    
   c_epoch_time=$( printf "%(%s)T" "now" )    
   d_epoch_time=$(( $c_epoch_time - $u_epoch_time ))    
   [ $d_epoch_time -gt 7200 ] && printf "%s User has session checked for more than %.0f Hours\n" "$user" "$(( $d_epoch_time / 60 / 60  ))" done < sample.log > UserlogsReport.log    

awk 'NF { id[$1]++; } END{ for (var in id) print var, "has", id[var], "sessions" }' sample.log > sessions_count.log    
awk '{ if ($3 >=2) print }' sessions_count.log      

Results  
zz006 has 2 sessions        
dd004 has 6 sessions    
bb002 has 5 sessions    
aa001 has 2 sessions
```

Notes:
1. I am comparing all login with current time, so in this sample all logins are older than two hours simply because login dates are older than current
2. In 2nd awk portion I am counting  and then outputing sessions which have count >= 2.

Comment: Hello Martin Konecny, I tried to code in two parts 1. Output those user ids where login time more than 24hrs, I have  epoch funtionlity ksh93 ‘ while read user v1 dt tm
do
   u_epoch_time=$( printf "%(%s)T" "${dt} ${tm}" )
   c_epoch_time=$( printf "%(%s)T" "now" )
   d_epoch_time=$(( $c_epoch_time - $u_epoch_time ))
   [ $d_epoch_time -gt 86400 ] && printf "%s User has login for %.0f days\n" "$user" "$(( $d_epoch_time / 60 / 60 / 24 ))"
done < file’

Comment: 2. 2nd part was to out only duplicate entries  and used awk for that
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]>1)for(i=1;i<=a[x];i++)print x}'

I could able to combine both in one script, but I am facing difficulties  to meet condition  1 from my note in original post.

Comment: Maybe edit your question, with that code so it's formatted properly.

Comment: @user3685993 Did you try the script I have provided below?

Comment: @jaypal Thanks lot for your help your code is very brief. But its working for the sample, but then I have tried by changing date and minute time, but results are consistent. e.g. Below change to user bb002, there are no sessiosn with difference of 2hrs, but I am still getting same results as "5".  bb002 2014/5/28 7:30
   bb002 2014/5/28 9:10
   bb002 2014/5/28 7:30
   bb002 2014/5/28 8:30
   bb002 2014/5/28 9:00
BTW the code I have updated, could you please help me to rewrite with more smarter way. I am not Linux or any othe code user, just exploring "awk" function to assist my job. Thanks!

Comment: @user3685993 I have updated the solution. If you have GNU `awk` then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
awk '
(($1,$2) in check) {
    split($2,d,/\//)
    split($3,t,/:/)
    time = mktime (d[1]" "d[2]" "d[3]" "t[1]" "t[2]" 00")
    if (time - check[$1,$2] >= 7200) {
        keep[$1]
    } 
    else {
        check[$1,$2] = time
    }
}
{
    split($2,d,/\//)
    split($3,t,/:/)
    time = mktime (d[1]" "d[2]" "d[3]" "t[1]" "t[2]" 00")
    count[$1]++; 
    check[$1,$2] = time
}
END {
    for (user in keep) 
        print user, count[user]
}' file
```

- We increment a `count` array for every user seen by doing `count[$1]++`.
- Create an array `check` with user and date as key and time as value (`check[$1,$2] = $3`)
- We test if user with same timestamp is present in our array. If it is we do the difference in time. If it is greater or equal to 7200 seconds, we store the user in `keep` array else we assign the new time for the user in `check` array.
- We keep doing this for the entire file
- In the `END` block we iterate our `keep` array and print the user along with the counts from `count` array.

**Update**:

- We use GNU `awk` `mktime` function to calculate the time difference by converting the date and time into seconds and check if the difference is greater than 7200 seconds (which is 2 hours).